# Xfce 4 Terminal how to wrap text

Tags: command-line, configuration, xfce, customization, appearance

I used to use the default `gnome-terminal` as my default Terminal, but because I want it to be see-through I have switched to the `xfce4-terminal`. But there is one problem, the text does not wrap, and I kind find anything in the Preferences that will allow me to wrap the text. So really that is my question, how do I wrap text in the Xfce 4 Terminal?

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: Xfce 4 No Wrap]

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Package Information:**

```
xfce4-terminal:
  Installed: 0.6.3-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 0.6.3-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 0.6.3-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot? I have line breaks, without me having to do anything.

Comment: @A.B.: Ok, I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Hmm, works fine with the same version, what is packaged?

Comment: When the problem occurs, after starting the command or until you change the window size?

Comment: @A.B.: Oh, that is just a custom alias of mine for `apt-get policy`... :D

Comment: @A.B.: It mostly happens when I change the window size, but it does also happen when I just execute the command.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: See egmont's comment on my answer, it's not possible with the current version of `xfce4-terminal`. The bugzilla tracker contains more info about the vte3 based version progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xfce4-terminal` uses vte to draw the actual terminal emulator and vte does not support line wrapping. With gnome3, `gnome-terminal` now uses vte3 and vte3 does support does line wrapping on resize events.

Note that vte is an old version without much development going on. So I would use `gnome-terminal` if you can.

To open the transparency settings go in `Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Colors`. Click on `use transparent background`.

Sources:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=175235
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1020186

Comment: vte3? `gnome-terminal` depends on `libvte-2.91 >= 0.40.2` and `xfce4-terminal` depends on `libvte9 >= 0.28`

Comment: @A.B. I was also confused by the version numbers but check https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vte3

Comment: Interesting, it's seems, that 2.91 is vte3

Comment: Anyway, good answer

Comment: Version numbers are a total chaos. There are 3 vte versions shipped in parallel by Ubuntu: the ancient gtk2-based vte <= 0.28 is called libvte9, the not-so-old gtk3 based vte between 0.30 and 0.36 are called libvte-2.90, and the newest (still gtk3 based, but with a slightly incompatible API) vte >= 0.38 is called libvte-2.91.

Comment: There will be an xfce-terminal based on newest vte one day, see https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11207 for progress. Until then I'd also much rather recommend a frontend using a new vte (e.g. gnome-terminal) than xfce-terminal.